# Swift Map Sorted Closure

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, mapping, closures

I am trying to understand closures in swift and am missing something fundamental.
Given the following example:

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
numbers.map({(number: Int) -> Int in return 3 * number})
numbers.map {(number: Int) -> Int in return 3 * number}
numbers.sorted {(n1:Int, n2:Int) -> Bool in return n1 < n2}
```

Why do the extra braces work for map but not sorted?
i.e.

```
numbers.sorted({(n1:Int, n2:Int) -> Bool in return n1 < n2})
```

does not compile...

```
"error: argument passed to call that takes no arguments"
```

Please could someone could explain the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because sort method is [func sorted(by:)](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/type/Array/#func-sorted-by_). So you have to add **`by`**
 param name:

```
numbers.sorted(by: {(n1:Int, n2:Int) -> Bool in return n1 < n2})
```

Comment: What is the conceptual distinction here? i.e. Why doesn't map have a **with:** (for example), or why **by:** is specified for sorted?

Comment: @DuncanRowland because as I mentioned in my answer, it returns a new array with the mapped result, it shouldn't map the array itself.

Comment: Thanks, but as you say, both **sorted** and **map** return new objects (only **sort** - which I wasn't thinking about - alters the existing instance).

Answer (score 4):

[sorted()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688066-sorted):

> A sorted array of the collection’s elements.

Means it returns a new -sorted- array, which it should assigned to a new instance. The simple way to implement it is:

```
let numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
let sortedNumbers = numbers.sorted { $0 < $1 } // [7, 12, 19, 20]
```

If you need to sort the array itself, use [sort()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688499-sort) instead:

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
numbers.sort { $0 < $1 }

print(numbers) // [7, 12, 19, 20]
```

*Note:* when using `sort()`, make sure that `numbers` array is var (mutable).

The same behavior is also appiled to [map(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688519-map):

> Returns an array containing the results of mapping the given closure
>   over the sequence’s elements.

You can also implment the `map()` in a simpler way:

```
let numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]

let mappedNumbers = numbers.map { $0 * 3 }

print(mappedNumbers) // [60, 57, 21, 36]
```

If you want to map the array itself, you should implement:

```
var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
numbers = numbers.map { $0 * 3 }

print(numbers) // [60, 57, 21, 36]
```

Or in a single line:

```
let numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12].map { $0 * 3 }

print(numbers) // [60, 57, 21, 36]
```